# Почему scanf не нужна звёздочка рядом с указателем?

Tags: c, указатели

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    int *p;
    p = &x;
    *p = 10;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    scanf("%d", p);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Почему, если делать через присваивание, чтобы в x записать новое значение, указатель берется со звездочкой. Но если то же самое делать ввод, то звездочка уже не нужна. p же это адрес, а не значение переменной по этому адресу.

Answer (score 3):

Звёздочка будет внутри функции `scanf`.

Представьте, что функция `scanf` доставляет посылку в какой-то дом. Номер дома записан в указателе `p`. Вы сообщили функции `scanf` номер дома, и поэтому она знает, куда доставить посылку (ввести значение). А если вы напишете `scanf("%d", *p)`, то вы сообщаете этой функции не номер дома, а то, что в этом доме находится. Спрашивается - куда теперь мне эту посылку доставить?

А вот где-то в недрах функции `scanf` будет примерно такой код:

```
int a = /*число, введённое с клавиатуры*/
*p = a; /*Доставляем посылку по адресу p*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `scanf` принимает на вход после форматной строки указатели на переменные, которым нужно присвоить значение из потока ввода. Чтобы в функции значение присвоилось переменной и сохранилось, необходимо передавать указатель на нее, и тогда можно будет после разыменования присвоить значение переменной.

При присваивании же указатель разыменовывается, чтобы получить доступ к значению переменой по ее адресу, а потом уже идет присваивание нового значения